# vuetifyjs form label location

Tags: vuetify.js

I can't arrange vuetify form label location. Below is my code:

```
<template>
        <v-container>
       <form @submit.prevent="signup">
            <v-col>
            <v-text-field
                v-model="form.name"
                label="Хэрэглэгчийн нэр"
                type="text"
                required>
            </v-text-field>
           </v-col>
       </form>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

The result looks in the below figure: [image]

Is this label available look on the left?

Comment: In your Vuetify configuration, is the `rtl` option set to `true`? This will cause the labels to be displayed on the right. Only use the `rtl` option for languages that are read from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override rtl style in labels by adding your custom `style`

```css
<style>

.v-label {
left: 0 !important;
right: auto !important;
}

</style>
```

Thi would make **ALL** labels move to left. If you want to apply this only on some inputs:

```css
<style>

.ltrLabel label {
left: 0 !important;
right: auto !important;
}

</style>
```

And on the inputs you want the label to be on the left:

```html
 <v-text-field
  v-model="form.name"
  label="Хэрэглэгчийн нэр"
  type="text"
  class="ltrLabel" <--- add ltrLabel class
  required>
  </v-text-field>
```